# NoMethodError in Classes#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get this error even though i defined @class = Class.all[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYoYM.png)

Controller code:

```
    class ClassesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
    before_action :set_class, only: [:show]
    def index
        @classes = Class.all
    end

    def show 

    end

    def new
        @class = Class.new
    end

    def create
        @class = Class.new  class_values
        @class.user_id = current_user.id
        if @class.save
            redirect_to  classes_path
        else
            render :new
        end
    end
end
```

And form code:

```
            <%= form_for @class do |f| %>

                <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :name %>
            <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :opis%>
            <%= f.text_area :opis, class: 'form-control'%>
                </div>



            <%= f.submit "Post", class: 'btn btn-outline-primary'%>
            <%= link_to  "Back", classes_path, class: 'btn btn-outline-secondary' %>
        <% end %>
```

I database i hvae table named classes with atributes user_id and name and opis(description)

Comment: See here http://reservedwords.herokuapp.com/  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694106/rails-reserved-class-names

Answer (score 1):

Your `Class` model is colliding with [Ruby](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Class.html) `Class` object. You need to choose a different name for your model.

Answer (score 0):

Class is not a good name for table, this is reserved word for Rails/Ruby and in other programming languages too. Consider changing it to something different